# How to make @EJB injection work on the server?

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173972/1270789), it says:

> If you don't want to use an Application Client Container and instead just run the application client class through a java command, injection won't be possible and you'll have to perform a JNDI lookup.

However, given that I am trying to inject a DAO bean [like the example shown here](http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/EJB3+Tutorial+2+-+Session+Bean+and+JPA#Session%20Bean%20and%20JPA-The%20Dao%20and%20its%20Interface), if I cannot do the automatic injecting, it means my application must manually do the JNDI lookup and all the transaction begin/end that I would get for free if the @EJB actually worked.

However, since everything is all within the same Eclipse EJB Project (it also failed with the same null handle when I had my client code in a Dynamic Web Project), surely there must be an easy way to get it all working? Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Finally, [this article suggests](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao) that DAOs are not needed, but if I replace within my EJB:

```
 @EJB MyDao dao;
```

with the more direct:

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
```

I still get the similar null value; is this the same injection failure problem?

---

**NB**: I have just noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485933/1270789):

> This is a [bug in Glassfish](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18406) (apparently in the web services stack).

I am running v4.0 Build 89, which still has this bug? Does this mean I have to do all JPA actions the long-winded way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out that the problem/issue is that in order to use injection of the `@PersistenceContext` the class **MUST** be a bean itself. This is hinted at in [the example on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans#Example):

```
@Stateless 
public class CustomerService { 

  @PersistenceContext 
  private EntityManager entityManager; 

  public void addCustomer(Customer customer) { 
    entityManager.persist(customer); 
  }
}
```

I could delete this question, but perhaps leaving this answer might provide a hint to someone, or at least show them a minimal working example of EJB and JPA.